# Why useRouteMatch not working as intended?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, router

Basically, I'm adding active class to navigation items which are clicked by using `useRouteMatch` to check if `to` is equal to the actual path. However when the path is `"/"` again, last active items still remains active. What can be the reason ?

```
function CustomLink ({to,exact,children,classes=''}) {
        const match = useRouteMatch({
            exact: exact,
            path: to
        });

        return(
            <Link className={match ? 'active ' + classes : ''} to={to}>{children}</Link>
        )
    }
```

```
<Router>
    <Link to="/" className="logo">
        <img src={require('../Assets/img/magical-logo.svg').default} alt=""/>
    </Link>
</Router>
<div className="the-rest">
    <Router>
        <nav>
            <CustomLink to="/readers" exact={true}>For readers</CustomLink>
            <CustomLink to="/authors" exact={true}>For authors</CustomLink>
            <CustomLink to="/about" exact={true}>About</CustomLink>
            <CustomLink to="/contact" exact={true}>Contact</CustomLink>
        </nav>
    </Router>
</div>
```

[image: See: The path is "/" but For Readers item is active]

Comment: If you console log, or inspect/debugger, the `match` result is it null or a defined object, when you are on your home (`"/"`) path/route?

Comment: Just found out the problem was that I used two separate Route elements inside the Component. When there's only one, everything works properly.

Comment: Ack, yeah, you can (should) use only one. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the problem was that I used two separate Route elements inside the Component. When there's only one, everything works properly.

So, instead of this:

```
<Router>
    <Link to="/" className="logo">
        <img src={require('../Assets/img/magical-logo.svg').default} alt=""/>
    </Link>
</Router>
<div className="the-rest">
    <Router>
        <nav>
            <CustomLink to="/readers" exact={true}>For readers</CustomLink>
            <CustomLink to="/authors" exact={true}>For authors</CustomLink>
            <CustomLink to="/about" exact={true}>About</CustomLink>
            <CustomLink to="/contact" exact={true}>Contact</CustomLink>
        </nav>
    </Router>
</div>
```

I used this:

```
<Router>
    <Link to="/" className="logo">
        <img src={require('../Assets/img/magical-logo.svg').default} alt=""/>
    </Link>
    <div className="the-rest">
        <nav>
            <CustomLink to="/readers" exact={true}>For readers</CustomLink>
            <CustomLink to="/authors" exact={true}>For authors</CustomLink>
            <CustomLink to="/about" exact={true}>About</CustomLink>
            <CustomLink to="/contact" exact={true}>Contact</CustomLink>
        </nav>
    </div>
</Router>
```

and it worked